# Does starch need to be cooked?

Tags: food, digestion

Does starch need to be cooked for human digestion ? Is the answer different for different starches; potato , wheat, corn, etc ?

Comment: See the post [Can we digest raw starch?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16891/can-we-digest-raw-starch) on cooking.SE.

Comment: I wonder why someone would call this question as "personal health advice"...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because duplicate of https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16891/can-we-digest-raw-starch